# How do I get this multipart/form-data request working with cURL in PHP?

Tags: php, curl, tiff

I'm having a difficult time POSTING to an API with PHP cURL. I feel I've tried every combination. My script is connecting but the issue is somewhere within the payload.

Here is the required request according to the documentation.

> --85b890d4-4faf-4261-bcbb-187c4dddcbc6 Content-Type: application/vnd.emc.ax+json; charset=utf-8 Content-Disposition:
>   form-data; name=data

```
{
"Name": "batch name",
"Description": "batch description",
 "Private": false
}
```

> --85b890d4-4faf-4261-bcbb-187c4dddcbc6 Content-Type: application/bin Content-Disposition: form-data; name=bin; filename="test.pdf";
>   filename*=utf-8''test.pdf
>
> //bin file content
>
> --85b890d4-4faf-4261-bcbb-187c4dddcbc6 Content-Type: application/bin Content-Disposition: form-data; name=annotation;
>   filename="0100002m.ano"; filename*=utf-8''0100002m.ano
>
> //annotation file content
>
> --85b890d4-4faf-4261-bcbb-187c4dddcbc6 Content-Type: application/bin Content-Disposition: form-data; name=text; filename="test.txt";
>   filename*=utf-8''test.txt
>
> //ocr file content
>
> --85b890d4-4faf-4261-bcbb-187c4dddcbc6--

Here is my code

```
$file = file_get_contents("tiff/test.TIF");

$curl = curl_init();
$data = array(
    'Content-Type: application/vnd.emc.ax+json; charset=utf-8 Content Disposition: form-data; name=data', 
    '{"Name":"Here is my Name","Description":"Testing This","Private":false}', 
    chunk_split(base64_encode($file))
);

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL =>"*********************************",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $d,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Authorization: **********************************",
        "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=85b890d4-4faf-4261-bcbb-187c4dddcbc6",

  ),
));

curl_close($curl);
```

My code produces this error:

> {"ErrorCode":9999,"Message":"Unexpected end of MIME multipart stream.
>   MIME multipart message is not complete.","InnerException":null}

will someone please help me?

Comment: I suggest you to use [Guzzle HTTP](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/) library for such implementation.

Comment: I just installed Guzzle. I'm getting this response. {"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}.

Comment: 'multipart' => [[ 'name' => 'foo',
                        'contents' => 'data',
                        'headers' => [
                        'Authorization' => '**********************************',
                                   'Content-Type'  => 'multipart/form-data',
                                   'Accept'        => 'application/vnd.emc.ax+json']
                   ],
                   [
                        'name'        => 'name',
                        'filename'   => 'testfile.txt',
                        'contents'   => $file,
                   ]],]);

Comment: Have you gotten this to work? I am getting the exact same error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did an implementation using pure CURL uploading files with multipart. Try this:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://youhosturl/path/to/you/endpoint \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -F 'my_file=@/Users/MyUser/Desktop/any-image.jpg'
```

This worked for me